# Rollover overlays with SVG

Tags: svg, overlay, raphael

i want to acheive the effect on [this page](http://www.topshop.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/CatalogNavigationSearchResultCmd?catalogId=33057&storeId=12556&langId=-1&viewAllFlag=false&categoryId=243998&interstitial=true&TS=1304585859188) using SVG. As you can see it uses a series of PNG transparent overlays when the user mouses over a polygonal hotspot drawn on a product.

What i want to achieve is the same thing with SVG, but without messing about with creating a load of PNGs, so that when the user mouses over an area the transparent shape (with link on it) appears over the top. The SVG shape would be built from a set of coordinates exactly as a polygonal hotspot would on an image map.

So i guess my first question is, can this be done with plain old SVG or do i need to use something like Raphael to achieve this? Never seen this effect before with SVG so if anyone has an example like that would be very useful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FWIW I think this effect is backwards with regards to what you would desire from a usability perspective. Rolling over an item makes it grey and dead and disabled looking? Instead, I would make all items start out faded and/or lower opacity and rolling over them makes them 'pop' with stronger, more vibrant colors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways to get this effect with plain old SVG. Probably the simplest is to use CSS within the SVG. For example:

```
<style>
  .overlay:hover
  {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
</style>

<svg>
  <a xlink:href="http://www.wherever/you/want/to/link/to.com">
    <path class="overlay" d="Coordinates of your shape..." />
  </a>
</svg>
```

I've written about various other methods at:
http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/data-visualisation/mouseover-effects-svgs

Comment: Note that opacity alone doesn't exactly mimic the referenced effect with simple uncropped images. For example, the sunglasses overlap the pants, but rolling over the sunglasses doesn't cause the pants to be visible through them.

Comment: True. If that's the effect required then I guess you could have a second, lighter image on top of the original with visibility="hidden" and a hover effect of visibility="visible".

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, much appreciated. Although ultimately i think i will have to go with a solution using Raphael simply because i need it to be cross browser compatible down to at least IE7.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it can be done with SVG only, with or without javascript.

One way to get the effect would be to overlay a white semi-transparent path on top of the image that you want to whiten. Another way would be to use an SVG filter to process the image directly, similar to what I've done [here](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/filters/hue-rotate-filter.svg) or [here](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/filters/lighter-color.svg) to recolor a PNG (view page source and feel free to reuse that in any way you like).

You'll want to make use of the ['pointer-events'](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/interact.html#PointerEventsProperty) property most likely. Here's an [example](http://dev.w3.org/SVG/profiles/1.1F2/test/harness/htmlObject/interact-pevents-09-f.html) showing how to detect mouse-events on the fill and/or stroke of an svg shape, even if the shape is invisible.